# How Do I Add a User to My AAD Tenant via portal.azure.com?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azureportal

At one point I created an AAD tenant & received a login of the form:

`<username>@<mywebsite>.onmicrosoft.com`

How do I add: `<ANOTHER-user>@<mywebsite>.onmicrosoft.com` using https://portal.azure.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Accessing your tenant:

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** You must be a global admin on your AAD tenant to perform these actions. If you created your tenant, you are a global admin by default.

1. Navigate to https://portal.azure.com & click "All services" in the ribbon on the left-hand side of your screen:

[image]

2. Start to type "azure active directory" into the search bar of the page that pops up. You will not need to type in the whole phrase to isolate AAD.
3. (Optional) Make sure the star next to Azure Active Directory is filled in to be able access AAD from the ribbon from image 1.
4. Click "Azure Active Directory":

[image]

5. In the resultant blade that pops up, click "Users" within the "Manage" section of the ribbon:

[image]

6. On this next blade click the "+ New user" button at the top. (Note that you cannot perform this step unless you are a global admin.):

[image]

### Creating another user under your tenant:

7. **IMPORTANT STEP:** You should now be on the "User" blade, Enter the first/last name of the user you would like to add. Use the "User name" section to **create** the username. Here, the domain I created when I made my AAD tenant is `buythingsfromus.onmicrosoft.com`, and so I'm giving "Person McHuman" the username: `phuman@buythingsfromus.onmicrosoft.com`
8. Click the profile tab, and fill out the requested info, then press "Ok" at the bottom. When you're done, you should see "Configured" under the word "Profile."
9. (Optional) If you would like to give the user permissions to add more users, change this setting to "Global Admin." If you don't leave it as-is.
10. Click the checkbox to show the temporary password that has been generated for this user, and copy it to provide to them. In this example, when Person first signs in with her phuman@buythingsfromus.onmicrosoft.com address, they will need this temporary password in order to create their permanent password.
11. Press "Create"
    [image]

### Validating the user you just created:

12. You should be brought back to the blade from Image 6. However this time, you should see Person McHuman's name and new "USER NAME" listed here:

[image]

13. Give Person her new `phuman@buythingsfromus.onmicrosoft.com` username and temporary password (Nozo7286 in this case.) In this image, the right-hand side shows Person trying to login to https://portal.azure.com for the first time.

[image]

14. Ms. McHuman will need to enter her temporary password here, and then create a new permanent one. Once she presses "Sign in" she will be good to go.